# How to use Window function in Redshift SQL

Tags: amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
Ans_cnt | Workloadid | Alias
10 | 1 | A
10 | 1 | B
10 | 1 | C
20 | 2 | D
20 | 2 | E
20 | 2 | F
```

---

```
create temp table test
(ans_cnt int, workloadid int, alias varchar(2));

insert into test values
(10, 1, 'A');
insert into test values
(10, 1, 'B');
insert into test values
(10, 1, 'C');
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
Ans_cnt | workloadid
10 | 1
20 | 2
```

i.e., for workloadid 1 the total ans_cnt is still 10. for workloadid 2 the total ans_cnt is still 20, just multiple aliases are assigned to the same workload. Hope that makes sense.

I tried doing sum by partitionin on workloadid but its not working:

```
select sum(ans_cnt) over (partition by workloadid) as ans_cnt from test
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in case you have different ans_cnt for same workload??

For e.g. in this case:

```
Ans_cnt | Workloadid | Alias
10 | 1 | A
10 | 1 | B
20 | 1 | C
10 | 2 | D
20 | 2 | E
30 | 2 | F
```

My guess is that you want to pick the highest number of ans_cnt per workloads.

If yes, you simply need this SQL:

```
select workloadid, max(ans_cnt) as ans_cnt from test
group by workloadid;
```

Which will give this as output:

```
Ans_cnt | Workloadid
20 | 1
30 | 2
```

OR if you want to pick the latest ans_cnt and your alias are alphabetically assigned, you need this SQL:

```
select ans_cnt, workloadid 
from (
       select ans_cnt, workloadid
         , row_number() over (partition by workloadid order by alias desc) as rnk 
       from test_1
) as t
where rnk=1
```